# Why aren't the values from the for loop appending to the array?

Tags: python, for-loop, append, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to append values from a for loop into a numpy array. While the values are correct, the array only returns none values. The values entered are from another numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

j=np.array([14,15,16,16,16,22,22,24,24,25,25,25,25,25])
u=np.unique(j)


def P(age):
    sum=0
    for i in range(14):
        if j[i]==age:
            sum=sum+1
        else:
            sum=sum
    print(sum/14)
    
p = []
for i in range(6):
    p.append(P(u[i]))
p=np.array(p)
print(p)
print(type(p))
```

Output:

```
0.07142857142857142
0.07142857142857142
0.21428571428571427
0.14285714285714285
0.14285714285714285
0.35714285714285715
[None None None None None None]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Can we see the output?

Comment: Corrected and added output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your function `P()` has no `return` statement, i.e. it returns `None`.

You probably want to change the last statement of this function definition, i.e. the statement

```
print(sum/14)
```

to

```
return sum/14
```

(or append this `return` statement after your `print(sum/14)`.)

Answer (score 0):

Function "P" doesn't have a return function, hence equaling None each time.

```
def P(age):
    sum=0
    for i in range(14):
        if j[i]==age:
            sum=sum+1
        else:
            sum=sum
    print(sum/14)
    return sum/14
```

Shown here ^, you can return the sum.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I didn't have it because I probably misplaced the return earlier and it was giving me some odd results, but this fixed it